# mongoengine reference field query

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm building a reservation site for a restaurant using flask framework and mongoengine.

My main object is to fetch all the reservation objects which customer id's equal to wanted customer id with json

```
data = rzv.objects(restaurant=rest, customer=cdb.objects.get(id=request.args.get("customer-reservation"))).all()
```

When i try to trigger this query json gives me an error:

```
mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError
```

My Reservation model below:

```
class Reservations(document.Document):
    restaurant = fields.ReferenceField(Restaurant)
    customer = fields.ReferenceField(Customers)
    shift_type = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Shifts)
    room = fields.ReferenceField(Rooms)
    time = fields.StringField()
    covers = fields.IntField()
    status = fields.StringField(default="wait")
    desk = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Desks)
    date = fields.DateTimeField()
    sit_date = fields.DateTimeField()
    end_sit_date = fields.DateTimeField()
    cancel_date = fields.DateTimeField()
```

My Customer model below:

```
class Customers(document.Document):
    title = fields.StringField()
    full_name = fields.StringField()
    first_name = fields.StringField()
    last_name = fields.StringField()
    telephone = fields.StringField()
    visits = fields.StringField()
```

Json:

```
$.getJSON("?customer-reservation=" + $(this).attr("data-id"), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            reservationFill(data);
        });
```

And finally the view:

```
    if request.args.get("customer-reservation"):
        data = rzv.objects(restaurant=rest, customer=cdb.objects.get(id=request.args.get("customer-reservation"))).all()
        return data
```

What is the right way to query this situation. Do i have to use a filter ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should split the query:

```
customer = Customers.objects(id=request.args.get("customer-reservation")).get()
data = Reservations.objects(restaurant=rest, customer=customer).all()
```

Also you will need error handling for any customers that don't match.

Comment: Will this be a performance bottleneck? This looks like we need to query (and then return) all fields of customer, and then query (and return) all fields of data.

Comment: Its multiple calls to the database and you should always minimise the amount of data transferred by projecting only the fields you need.  You could also limit the data returned to further lower the cost over the network. It depends on your business logic and requirements.  As to being a bottleneck - that depends on the whole stack

Answer (score 4):

You can use in – value is in list (a list of values should be provided) in a single line:

```
data = Reservations.objects(restaurant=rest, 
               customer__in=Customers.objects.filter(id="your filter id")).all()
```

Comment: nice solution helped me!